# Why mouse event is not fired when inside listview?

Tags: wpf, listview, events, mvvm, mouseevent

I am using `System.Windows.Interactivity` and i have to display a Message on mouse enter event.
The problem is the same event is called when done outside the ListView, But it gets not called when inside the ListView.

I tried doing so using mvvm approach:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="events1">
      //This Event works outside the ListView but not inside ListView
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="30">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
        <ListView BorderBrush="#FF1D93E4" BorderThickness="4" Behaviour:GridViewColumnResize.Enabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem ,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Ur1r2_Obj}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" Behaviour:GridViewColumnResize.Width="*">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}">
                                    //The event do not work here
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                    <Button Margin="35,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Etat, Mode=OneWay}" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In view Model

```
 private ICommand someCommand;
        public ICommand SomeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                //return plotButton;
                return someCommand ?? (someCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyAction2(), _canExecute));
            }
            set
            {
                someCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeCommand");

            }
        }

       private void MyAction2() //Messsage is popuped on Moseenter event when i try to hover mouse  over rectangle outside the listview , But not get called when inside the Listview
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yeah Called");
        }
```

Why it event is not called from inside the ListView. How to make it call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to invoke the same command (SomeCommand) you should specify a RelativeSource of the Binding:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Button Margin="35,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Etat, Mode=OneWay}" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

The DataContext of an item in the ListView is an object in your "Ur1r2_Obj" ItemsSource whereas the DataContext of the Rectangle is your view model. That's why the binding fails in your CellTemplate.

Comment: Thankyou so much. But how will i get the data corresponding to that mousentered row ?

Comment: You could pass the object in the ItemsSource as a CommandArgument to the command: <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />